# Visual Studio 2010 compiling .cpp files as .c files

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm working one a Visual Studio solution which was generated using CMake (not sure if this is relevant).

In this solution there a c file, I wanted to change it into a cpp file, so I renamed it and changed the extension.

However, Visual Studio still treats it like a c file and gives compiler errors whenever I add any c++ style code.

I'm stuck, any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Project Properties, Configuration, C/C++, Advanced, change "Compile As".

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be an obvious solution.